# How can I create a static library in nasm and link with gcc?

Tags: c++, gcc, static-libraries, nasm

I would like to implement a number of functions in (32bit) NASM that have the following signature:

```
int function1();
int function2();
```

etc.

Then I want to create an object file and be able to statically link it with a C++ program compiled with gcc. I am looking for an example implementation of a function that returns an int, any additional code needed to export the symbols and the command line for NASM to produce a .a file that I can link to statically. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't think NASM will produce a .a file, but you can easily make one from a .o by using ar. And you don't necessarily need a .a file to link; you can just link the .o file directly. So I think all you need to know is how to write the assembly function to be compatible with the gcc calling convention. You'll likely want `extern "C"` on your prototypes. Here's a link that might help http://wiki.osdev.org/C%2B%2B_to_ASM_linkage_in_GCC

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assembler will output an object file, just use it when linking (I don't remember NASM options, so don't try this verbatim — something like `nasm foo.asm -o foo.o; g++ -o prog foo.o bar.cpp`).

Static libraries are nothing more than fancy archives (hence the .a extension) of object files. binutils has `ar` utility if you really want to pack a single object into an archive.

Comment: How can I export the functions (from nasm code) such that I can use them as extern "C" declarations?

Comment: @TamásSzelei: Read NASM docs, I can't recall. Also, writing anything in assembly is probably a bad idea, anyway.

Comment: That's kind of why I asked the question. I couldn't find the relevant parts in the documentation. And thanks for the advice, noted. I have a reason to do so (it is not performance).

Comment: @TamásSzelei: http://www.nasm.us/doc/nasmdoc6.html#section-6.6 Also read up on cdecl calling convention.

Comment: Thanks. I actually couldn't link the resulting COFF object (-f coff), but I tried FASM and the "MS COFF" format it produced was (oddly) linkable by ld.